# Facebook won't show feed unless user is logged in

Tags: feed, facebook-iframe

We have integrated a Facebook feed on our site. It only works if the user is logged in on Facebook. If the user is offline the feed tells the user to log in (the feed does not show up).
(Example, you have to log out to see the problem).

Answer (score 3):

Most probably you haven't published your Page yet:

> This page can't be seen by the current user. Please check page privacy
>   and visibility settings.

[image: Page not published]